# Java Compiler Android App

Tags: java, android

I want to make a java compiler android app. I am able to run java file into another java file from the below code, but it is not working in android.
It gives error javac not found.

```
public class JavaCompiler { 

      private static void printLines(String cmd, InputStream ins) throws  Exception {

          String line = null;

          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ins));

          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(cmd + " " + line);
          }

       }

       public static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {

          Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c "+command);

          printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
          printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());

          pro.waitFor();

          System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
       }

}
```

and my activity code

```
 File file=new File("/sdcard/java/NewJava.java");

 JavaCompiler.runProcess("javac -cp src "+file.getPath());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android contains few command-line programs. `javac` is not one of them.

Comment: then what I have to do do run java program in android app?

Comment: @Bansal: That is not really what Android is designed for. You are welcome to try to port the OpenJDK edition of `javac` and related tools to run on Android's CPU architectures, system libraries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

javac is not part of android - depending on what you want to do you might want to try bean-shell. Have a look here: https://github.com/ligi/Ajsha